# insertion sort code using insert and insertsort!

Tags: c

i have written a code for insertion sort but it is nt  sorting..
kindly help me out in making the desired changes to mycode.
thanx

```
#include<stdio.h>

int compare(int a,int b)

{

if(a>b)

return 1;

else if( a<b)

return -1;

else if(a==b)

return 0;

}


void insert(int m, int ms[], int size)

{   

    int j,k;

    for (j=0; j<size; j++)   // Find the right position

       { if (compare(m, ms[j])) break;

    // Assertion: j is the right position for m

          for (k=size-1; k>=j; k--)  // Right shift values>m

       ms[k+1] = ms[k];

    ms[j] = m; } // Insert m

}



void insertSort(int ms[], int size)

{   

    int j;

    // Loop Invariant: 

    //  The sublist from ms[0] to ms[j-1] is sorted

    for (j=1; j<size; j++) {

         insert(ms[j], ms, j);

    }

}



void main()

{

int i,arr[5]={55,66,22,44,39};

printf("sorting\n");

insertSort(arr,5);



for( i=0;i<5;i++)

{

printf("\n%d",arr[i]);

}

}
```

this is my xact code..
i have to use the two functions insert and insert sort!

Comment: Sorry, but "Please fix this jumble of code" is not a question.

Comment: you're going to have to specify which function you think the problem is in at the very least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're testing the return value of `compare` incorrectly.  You probably want something like this:

```
if (compare(m, ms[j]) <= 0) break;
```

Also, remove the curly braces inside function `insert`, they are screwing the structure of your code.  The statements following the `break` should not be inside the first loop's body.

By the way, if you make your code simpler and tidier, you'll be less likely to make silly mistakes.  Proper indentation will help you visualize the structure of your code easily.  For example:

```
void insort(int a[], int n, int e) {
    int j;
    for (j = n - 1; j >= 0 && a[j] > e; j--)
        a[j + 1] = a[j];
    a[j + 1] = e;
}
void insertion_sort(int a[], int n) { 
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        insort(a, i, a[i]);
}
```